# How to delete a search index on the App Engine using Go?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, gae-search

I am wondering what is the best way to delete a search index of the full text search API that is available on the Google App Engine. I have found a few questions on this topic focusing on Python, but none on Go. The general suggestions seems to be to manually delete all documents in the search index and than call `index.delete_schema()`, see for example[0].

However, for Go there seems to be no function to delete a schema. I have used a task queue to remove every document in an index, but the size of the index shown in the App Engine Dashboard did not decrease.

[0] [How to delete or reset a search index in Appengine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388251/how-to-delete-or-reset-a-search-index-in-appengine/14390379#14390379)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you delete documents, the space usage shown on the Dashboard is not updated immediately.  It is recalculated by a nightly batch job.  So it should be updated within 24 hours.

Comment: It is updated now, but it took a few days instead of 24 hours. Not sure why. Anyway, thanks for the answer.